How to show that the trivial group is the free group of the empty set (using universal property of free groups)?
Aluffi (in Algebra: Chapter 0) says that given a set $A$, the free group is a group $F(A)$ together with a set map $j_*:A\to F(A)$ st for any group $G$ and any set map $f:A\to G$, there is a unique group map $\varphi:F(A)\to G$ st $\varphi j_*=f$.
He also claims that the trivial group $\{e\}$ is (ie satisfies the universal property for) the free group of $A$. Here, I take the map $j_*$ to be the empty map $\emptyset \to \{e\}$ as it is the unique set map with this choice of (co)-domain by initiality of $\emptyset$ in the category of sets.
The group map $\{e\}\to G$ must map $e$ to the neutral element $e_G$, and hence it is the unique group map $\{e\}\to G$. But how to show that the resulting triangle commutes?
I believe it is related to composition with the empty map. But I am unsure how to proceed. Any suggestions will be helpful :)

There is a notational problem with your post, which might clear things up: you seem to be using two different notations for the trivial group, ${e}$ and ${*}$.

The "triangle"commutes because the embedding of the empty set into the trivial group is the empty function, so you are trying to show the empty function into $G$ equals the composition of the empty map into ${*}$ followed by the trivial map to $G$. They are both the empty map from $\varnothing$ to $G$.

@LeeMosher I overlooked that while typing. Now I have changed it all to ${e}$.

@ArturoMagidin I was thinking the same, but I didn't know how to show that composition of map with the empty map is the empty map.

You have already written the words you need: the empty map exists and is unique for any choice of codomain.

Oh yeah, thanks.

@ArturoMagidin If you can make your comment an answer, I will accept it :))

For any set $A$, there is one and only one function $\varnothing\to A$, namely the empty function. We consider two empty function $\varnothing \to A$ and $\varnothing\to A'$ to be "equal" if and only if they have the same codomain.
Why is $\{e\}$, together with the empty function $\iota\colon\varnothing\to\{e\}$, the free group on $\varnothing$? Because it satisfies the universal property:

Let $G$ be any group. We need to show that given any set function $f\colon \varnothing \to G$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\phi\colon\{e\}\to G$ such that $f = \phi\circ\iota$.

Indeed, let $G$ be any group. There is only one possible choice for $f$, the empty function. And there is only one possible choice for $\phi$, namely $\phi\colon\{e\}\to G$ given by $\phi(e)=e_G$.  We then need to show that the empty function $f\colon\varnothing\to G$ is equal to $\phi\circ\iota$. This is a function with domain $\varnothing$ and codomain $G$. So it is the empty function from $\varnothing$ to $G$, which is the same as $f$. Thus, $f=\phi\circ\iota$, as desired. Since $\phi$ is the unique group homomorphism $\{e\}\to G$, it is also the unique morphism that satisfies $f=\phi\circ\iota$, establishing the universal property.
